# ¿Como puedo darle dos acciones diferentes a un boton en html con js?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente botón dentro de un formulario html:

```
<button type="reset" onchange="javascript:validate()" class="send-btn ml-md-1">Modificar</button>
```

La función reset funciona correctamente, me borra todos los campos de mi formulario a excepción del siguiente select (el cual también se encuentra dentro de mi form):

```
<select id="select" name="select">
     <option value="null">Servicios</option>
     <option value="Impresiones">Impresiones</option>
     <option value="Copias">Copias</option>
</select>
```

Intenté con js, le otorgé un valor nulo a la primera opción y traté de validar ese valor con js, mi código es este:

```
function validate() {
    var select = document.getElementsById("select").values;
    if (select == "null") {
        alert("Seleccione una opción");
    }
}
```

Pero no funciona, solo me valida los demás campos pero el select no, necesito ayuda.

Comment: en la funcion validate cambia values por value, sin la s.

Comment: Listo pero sigue igual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo tu codigo con unos detalles:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

function validate() {
    var select = document.getElementById("select").value;
    if (select == "null") {
        alert("Seleccione una opción");
    }
}

</script>
<select id="select" name="select">
     <option value="null">Servicios</option>
     <option value="Impresiones">Impresiones</option>
     <option value="Copias">Copias</option>
</select>

<br>
<button type="reset" onclick="validate()" class="send-btn ml-md-1">Modificar</button>
```

Cambie el Onchange por Onclick y el getElementById tenia una S extra

PD: un boton funciona es con Onclick y los selects o Checkboxs alli si puedes usar el onchange

Comment: Excelente si me funcionó, ¡gracias!